Determine $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n n!}{n^n}$
The task is to determine the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n n!}{n^n}.
$$
I tried to transform this expression, like
$$
\frac{2^n n!}{n^n}=\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^n\cdot n!=\frac{\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^n}{\frac{1}{n!}}
$$
So maybe L'Hospital is an option? But I did not succeed in doing so.
Do you have some hint, please?

Have you heart about the Stirling approximation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)?

Unfortunately, I did not.

I guess you could use that to finish your problem. Another option, although I'm not sure if it would work, to use the L'Hopital treating $n!$ as $\Gamma(n+1)$, but that's probably an overkill.

You can show via induction that $n! <n^{n+1}e^{-n}$, for $n\ge 3$.

@Gary If I do so, I get that
$$
\frac{2^n n!}{n^n}<\frac{2^n\cdot n}{e^n}.
$$
What's next?

@selector Since $2/e<1$ and $2^n n!/n^n >0$ you immediately have your answer via squeeze theorem.

Sorry, it should be $n! <e \cdot n^{n+1}e^{-n}$.

I am still not sure how to continue. Using $n!<e\cdot n^{n+1}e^{-n}$, what I get is
$$
0<\frac{2^nn!}{n^n}< \left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^n\cdot e\cdot n.
$$
The first factor on the RHS tends to $0$ but how to continue? Tried to apply L'Hospital.

From the ratio test for sequences we know that if $$a_n>0, \exists\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\ell$$ then $$\begin{cases}\ell>1\implies a_n\to\infty\\\ell\in(0,1)\implies a_n\to 0^+\end{cases}$$
in your case $a_n=\frac{2^n n!}{n^n}$, so:

 $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2^{n+1}\cdot (n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\frac{n^n}{2^n\cdot n!}=\frac{2(n+1)n^n}{(n+1)(n+1)^n}=2\bigg(\frac{n}{n+1}\bigg)^n=$$$$=2\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg)^n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{e}$$
 and obviously $\frac{2}{e}<1$ so $a_n\to0^+$


We can say even more: the series $\sum \frac{2^n}{n! n^n} $ converges, so the sequence must converge to $0$

Yes, but first you should prove that it converges. By the way $n!$ is on the numerator, so the convergence is not so immediate without the ratio test

Sorry for my typo. By the way, I meant that the series converges by the ratio test, so the limit of the sequence is $0$

I agree with you

How do you get from $(n/(n+1))^n$ to $(1-(1/n))^n$?

It should be $\left ( 1 - \frac{1}{n+1} \right) ^n$, but the limit is the same

$\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n = \left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} \cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{-1} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{e}$
